# Python: Is there easier way of doing this? String to certain text

Tags: python, string, key, getvalue

I have this list:

```
comment = ['Item Location: AUMEL222\nLintu Testi: C:\\SSD\\important\\text.txt\nLintu Connection: 123\nItem Version: ABC.123.ABC\nItem Serial: 1234ABCD\nItem Configuration ID: ABCD1234']
```

i need to extract certain items from here. And i have made it work, but there must be more simple way to do this. My code looks like this:

```
key = "Item Location"
key_found = False
for line in comment:
    if key_found:
        get_value(line)     #converts the big list to more readable state.
line2 = line
teststat = ""
FW = ""
print(line2)
for item in line2.split("\n"):
        if "Item Location" in item:
               Teststat = (item.strip())
        if "Item Version" in item:
                FW = (item.strip())
print(Teststat)
print(FW)
```

outputs:

```
Item Location : AUMEL222
Item Version : ABC.123.ABC
```

So grabbing few wanted values from a string.
The main goal is to only print out the Value. Not the key. But it can be done with:

```
print(Teststat.replace("Item Location: ", ""))
```

Comment: I really don't get it. Please tell me what is the input and what do you want as output.

Comment: input is the list "comment" and wanted output is the same output but with more simple code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want something like this;

```
comment = ['Item Location: AUMEL222\n'
           'Lintu Testi: C:\\SSD\\important\\text.txt\n'
           'Lintu Connection: 123\n'
           'Item Version: ABC.123.ABC\n'
           'Item Serial: 1234ABCD\n'
           'Item Configuration ID: ABCD1234']
comment = comment[0]

for key_value_pair in [key_value_pair.split(':') 
                       for key_value_pair in comment.split('\n')]:
    print(':\t'.join(key_value_pair))
```

Note that I have simply put parts of your string inside the list onto new lines for readability, this hasn't made any change to the value of `comment`.

---

Outputs:

```
Item Location:   AUMEL222
Lintu Testi:     C: \SSD\important\text.txt
Lintu Connection:    123
Item Version:    ABC.123.ABC
Item Serial:     1234ABCD
Item Configuration ID:   ABCD1234
```

Comment: with: 

    print(key_value_pair[1])

exactly what i was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are often overkill but they are a good match (lame pun, sorry) here:

```
import re
for line in comments:
    found = re.findall(r"(^Item Location|Item Version): (.+?)$", line, re.MULTILINE)
    if found:
        print(found)
        # if you only want the values:
        print("\n".join(v for k, v in found))
        # if you want it as a dict for future use
        found = dict(found)
        print(found)
        # etc
```

Comment: Works, Thanks. Really Lame Pun.  But going with Tom's Answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `item.split(':')[1]`instead of `item.strip()`.

Comment: doesn't really make it shorter or more simple

Comment: If you want to make it shorter, you can try the regular expressions with `re` package but I think that it's a pretty harder way.

Comment: true. I looked into it and didn't seem like worth using it

Answer (score 0):

```
comment = ['Item Location: AUMEL222\nLintu Testi: C:\\SSD\\important\\text.txt\nLintu Connection: 123\nItem Version: ABC.123.ABC\nItem Serial: 1234ABCD\nItem Configuration ID: ABCD1234']
key = 'Item Location'

#split with \n
commentSplit = comment[0].split('\n')
commentSplit2 = []

#split with ':'
for i in commentSplit:
    commentSplit2.append(i.split(':'))

#value for key
for i in commentSplit2:
 if i[0] == key:
     print i[1]
```